# Character animation with bones for AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, animation

I'm developing some platform-like game in Flash using AS3. Everything is quite clean. The whole code is class based etc.
I've already done the most of the mechanics, and now I need to do some main character animations. I've already designed it, and it's waiting to be animated as a vector graphics.
A the problem starts here... What is the proper way of doing that? I would like to use bone tools to make it smooth. But as far as I tried to find  any materials about it on the Internet everybody just do some simple animations and play it separately one after another. How about playing legs animation simultaneously arms and other parts of the body? Maybe some tricky usage of state machine... I don't know.. Is there any ready solution for that?
More tips is better here, or even some tutorials - just anything.

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial by Chris Georgenes seems to be exactly what your looking for: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/character_animation_ik.html. Chris teaches the reader while animating a simple character. Having a strong overall knowledge of the bone tool will allow you to get the nice crisp animations you seek. I sincerely wish you the best of luck with your project.

Comment: Not really, no. I saw it already earlier. It just shows how to add bones on very simple project. But it does not show how to deal with multiple animations in a 'real world' played simultaneously and how to blend them up between changing animations. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: It sounds like what your looking for is how to animate pieces through code to other positions?